# ssis derived column format

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

in ssis I'm loading a data file that has a date field formatted as 11171977 into a table with a data type of varchar(8).

i can load this into the table fine; however, I need to reformat the data as yyyymmdd so it is 19771117.

my first attempt was to load as is then query with the following convert:

```
convert(varchar(8),convert(date,substring (BirthDate,1,2)+'/'+substring (BirthDate,3,2)+'/'+substring (BirthDate,5,4),101), 112)
```

that gives me yyyymmdd = 19771117.

however, I tried to do a derived column with no luck as it didn't like my expression.

how do i do this in an expression in the derived column?

Comment: Sounds like your destination table data type is VARCHAR(8), Why go from string to date back to string when the string just needs a simple rearrangement?

Comment: so if i use a derived column, how would i do a string rearrangement?

Comment: Look for a substring() function!
Have you already tried this? Show us what exactly you have tried.

Comment: right(BirthDate,4)+left(BirthDate,2)+substring(BirthDate,3,2)

Comment: I think you could simplify it to right(BirthDate,4)+left(BirthDate,4). Do you get an error?

Comment: the expression i wrote worked!

Comment: Great, but I still think you should simplify it!

Comment: i think I will use your approach.

Comment: The two approaches are functionally equivalent, mine is just a little simpler. Take care!

Comment: Thank you; so how do you get credit for helping?

Comment: I am not sure this discussion deserves credit; I will post my answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
right(BirthDate,4)+left(BirthDate,4)
```